# Replace values in list using Python

Tags: python, list, performance, replace

I have a list where I want to replace values with None where condition() returns True.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

For example, if condition checks bool(item%2) should return:

```
[None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: use the itertools module, it's the most efficient.

Comment: For `in-place` replacement comparisons, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203748/307454)

Comment: Wow. This question(2009) already has answers from the *future*(2010). So, the important question: How can I time travel? :)

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Build a new list with a list comprehension:

```
new_items = [x if x % 2 else None for x in items]
```

You can modify the original list in-place if you want, but it doesn't actually save time:

```
items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    if not (item % 2):
        items[index] = None
```

Here are (Python 3.6.3) timings demonstrating the non-timesave:

```
In [1]: %%timeit
   ...: items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   ...: for index, item in enumerate(items):
   ...:     if not (item % 2):
   ...:         items[index] = None
   ...:
1.06 µs ± 33.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   ...: new_items = [x if x % 2 else None for x in items]
   ...:
891 ns ± 13.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And Python 2.7.6 timings:

```
In [1]: %%timeit
   ...: items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   ...: for index, item in enumerate(items):
   ...:     if not (item % 2):
   ...:         items[index] = None
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 µs per loop
In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   ...: new_items = [x if x % 2 else None for x in items]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 µs per loop
```

Comment: is that the most efficient? doesn't enumerate have to create an iterator and form a tuple, adding overhead? are lists in python arraylists, giving you constant time access?

Comment: I think, and I might be wrong, that he meant for a copy of the list to be returned instead of modifying the original in place. But still, +1 for offering the efficient solution when in-place modification is allowed.

Comment: If I wanted to modify the original in place, wouldn't it also possible to use imap from itertools?

Comment: @geowa4: Python "lists" are actually arrays. `enumerate()` will ad a small overhead, but if that's unacceptable the index can be tracked manually. @ak: I don't understand the question. `imap()` is not an in-place operation.

Comment: @John Millikin: I was just thinking, what if I had a generator that yields the values from range(11) instead of a list. Would it be possible to replace values in the generator?

Comment: Generators don't have values to replace; when called, their `next()` method returns values until eventually it doesn't. This is a useful API for generic iteration, but it prevents some performance optimizations.

Comment: @JohnMillikin Please comment on my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203748/307454) for a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201926/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list-in-python-in-place/24203748#24203748)

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  But isn't there enough of a use case here for python lists to have a replace method?  (similar to str.replace).  Something that avoids the need for this: `def replace(items, a, b): return [b if x == a else x for x in items]`

Comment: I like this answer, but if you want predefined indecies, say: `RemoveItems = [1,3,4]` then you can retain the `enumerate` command like so `[None if n in RemoveItems else item for n,item in enumerate(items)]`

Comment: I think you got "easiest to read" and "most efficient" backwards

Comment: Python 3 is really 100x faster than Python 2 for this task?

Comment: You can modify the list in place and use a comprehension at the same time: `items[:] = [b if x == a else x for x in items]`.

Answer (score 79):

```
ls = [x if (condition) else None for x in ls]
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way:

```
>>> L = range (11)
>>> map(lambda x: x if x%2 else None, L)
[None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None]
```

Comment: @gath: Don't aspire to write one-liners for every purpose. Sometimes, they increase readability or performance, but often they don't. As to hints: Get to know the tools that Python ofters, especially list (and for Python 3 also dict) comprehensions, the ternary operator, anonymous (lambda) functions, and functions like map, zip, filter, reduce, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Riffing on a side question asked by the OP in a comment, i.e.:

> what if I had a generator that yields
>   the values from range(11) instead of a
>   list. Would it be possible to replace
>   values in the generator?

Sure, it's trivially easy...:

```
def replaceiniter(it, predicate, replacement=None):
  for item in it:
    if predicate(item): yield replacement
    else: yield item
```

Just pass any iterable (including the result of calling a generator) as the first arg, the predicate to decide if a value must be replaced as the second arg, and let 'er rip.

For example:

```
>>> list(replaceiniter(xrange(11), lambda x: x%2))
[0, None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None, 10]
```

Comment: +1 hehe... i want to learn how to write this "one" line nifty python solution... hint pls

Comment: @gath, I don't understand your question -- comments are pretty limiting so you should open a new question so you can expand and clarify what is it you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = range (11)
>>> [ x if x%2 == 1 else None for x in L ]
[None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to replace values in place, you can
update your original list with values from a list
comprehension by assigning to the whole slice of the original.

```
data = [*range(11)] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
id_before = id(data)
data[:] = [x if x % 2 else None for x in data]
data
# Out: [None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None]
id_before == id(data)  # check if list is still the same
# Out: True
```

If you have multiple names pointing to the original list,
for example you wrote `data2=data` before changing the list
and you skip the slice notation for assigning to `data`,
`data` will rebind to point to the newly created list while `data2` still points to the original unchanged list.

```
data = [*range(11)] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data2 = data
id_before = id(data)
data = [x if x % 2 else None for x in data]  # no [:] here
data
# Out: [None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None]
id_before == id(data)  # check if list is still the same
# Out: False
data2
# Out: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note: This is no recommendation for generally preferring one over the other
(changing list in place or not), but behavior you should be aware of.

Answer (score -7):

This might help...

```
test_list = [5, 8]
test_list[0] = None
print test_list
#prints [None, 8]
```

Comment: Can you explain some about why you think it might help?

Comment: @T-Heron It could be modified to fulfill what the question is asking for

Comment: If it needs to be *modified*, then it isn't an answer to the question that is being asked. Please either make (or explain) the necessary modifications yourself, or delete the answer.

Comment: This is hard coding , i don't think best way to do it .

Comment: This is not useful in a real usage scenario.