# In-place replacement of all occurrences of an element in a list in python

Tags: python, list, replace, in-place

Assume I have a list:

```
myl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6]
```

What is the most efficient and simplest pythonic way of **in-place** (*double emphasis*) replacement of all occurrences of `4` with `44`?

I'm also curious as to why there isn't a `standard` way of doing this (especially, when `strings` have a *not-in-place* [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method)?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Not a duplicate. More often than not, answers for similar questions don't focus on the in-place requirement.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe -- Not exactly.  That doesn't specify the _in-place_ constraint.  I'd be surprised if there _isn't_ some other dupe around here, but that's not it ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: The other question I referenced doesn't specify a "out-of-place" constraint either. In that sense, it's a superset. Consequently, the answers to the questions give in-place as well as out-of-place (hm, not sure that's a good inverse of in-place :) answers. So I guess you're right - it's not a duplicated but "related". I retracted my vote.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe -- Definitely related.  No argument there :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I would actually argue [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2582138/307454) is probably a good candidate for duplicate; as a matter fact, I wanted to post my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203748/307454) there, but the question was already closed for various reasons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can iterate over the list with `enumerate` and replace the old value with new value, like this

```
myl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6]
for idx, item in enumerate(myl):
    if item == 4:
        myl[idx] = 44
print myl
# [1, 2, 3, 44, 5, 44, 44, 44, 6]
```

Answer (score 31):

```
myl[:] = [x if x != 4 else 44 for x in myl]
```

Perform the replacement not-in-place with a list comprehension, then slice-assign the new values into the original list if you really want to change the original.

Comment: Only thing is we have to construct a new list and replace the old one with the new one. My version might be efficient here. Have to `timeit` and confirm.

Comment: @thefourtheye replacing the list comprehension with a generator expression may help.

Comment: @bereal Please show me how!

Comment: @lifebalance I was thinking about `myl[:] = (x if x != 4 else 44 for x in myl)`, that turned out to be slower, however.

Comment: @bereal: [`list_ass_slice`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/55fed3eae14b/Objects/listobject.c#l613) calls `PySequence_Fast` on the thing it's assigning to the slice, which kills any benefit of using a generator.

Comment: @thefourtheye The old list is not replaced with a new one, the old one gets modified in place with slice-assignment. You can check with `id(myl)` before and after slice-assignment, it's still the same afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

```
for  item in myl:
   if item ==4:
      myl[myl.index(item)]=44
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything to `myl`.

Comment: Lol, I am just trying...very new to python

Comment: That's fair enough :) everyone was new at some point, but that's no excuse for writing bad answers that might mislead someone in the future.

Comment: Besides, even if you manage to assign it that way, that will iterate through the whole list prefix for every `4` found. Makes `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @apomene -- I've written many bad answers in my day.  Fortunately there's a little "delete" button/link thing so that I could erase it :-)

Comment: I will try to improve it as a start...

Comment: @Ffisegydd Could you show me your code for timing the various answers?

Comment: @Ffisegydd, Appreciate this, as wel as or your comments because I amange to understand my error and fix my code

Comment: @apomene I'm guessing that your performance might still go further up if you use exceptions?

Comment: @Ffisegydd: If the thing to replace shows up extremely rarely, the overhead of creating tuples and other stuff the other answers do can cause them to run slightly slower. If it shows up more, especially at the end of the list, this answer's performance degrades rapidly.

Comment: @lifebalance here's how to time code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score -2):

```
while True:
    try:
        myl[myl.index(4)] = 44
    except:
        break
```

The `try-except` approach, although more **pythonic**, is less efficient. This [timeit program on ideone](http://ideone.com/fC6oA5) compares at least two of the answers provided herein.

Comment: This isn't more efficient. It only looks so good because you accidentally used brackets for `myl.index[4]` instead of parentheses. It immediately TypeErrors, but the `except` hides the error, so it looks like it finishes instantly. Correct that, and it doesn't look so good. If you move the `4`s later in the list, after the big block of 100 `100`s, or if you add more `4`s, the performance disadvantage of this becomes clearer. Build a list with a high percentage of `4`s, and performance takes a nosedive.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing our the coding error.