# Removing <br> tag for proper alignment while webscraping using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to remove the `<br>` html tag while web scraping the page, but replace doesn't seem to work. i'm not sure if there is another way to do it or better way to do it using selenium and python. thank you in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("drivers/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")

state_drop = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
state = Select(state_drop)
state.select_by_visible_text("New Hampshire")

driver.find_element_by_id("city").send_keys("Moultonborough")
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Moultonborough Academy")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("forms_input_button").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_id("hsSelectRadio_1").click()

courses_subheading = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("th.header")

print(courses_subheading[0].text, "     " ,courses_subheading[1].text, "     ", courses_subheading[2].text, "     ", courses_subheading[3].text, "     ", courses_subheading[4].text
```

I tried this:

```
for i in courses_subheading:
    courses_subheading.replace("<br>", " ")
```

but get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

currently, it looks like this:

```
Course
Weight     Title     Notes     Max
Credits       OK
Through       Disability
Course
```

but i want it like this:

```
Course Weight     Title     Notes     Max Credits     OK     Through     Disability Course
```

Comment: Hi, have a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201926/in-place-replacement-of-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list-in-python       your loop to replace <br> was close, you just need to use the iterator not the list

Comment: in your loop instead of :

    `courses_subheading.replace("<br>", " ")`

use:
       `i.replace("<br>", " ")`

Comment: @J.Doe This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: thank you for catching that, but i'm still getting an error regarding attribute ```AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'replace'```. also, i gave the possible solution to give context to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the `<br>` you can easily avoid the `<br>` tags. To print the table headers, e.g.  **Title**, **Notes**, etc, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "state")))).select_by_visible_text("New Hampshire")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#city").send_keys("Moultonborough")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#name").send_keys("Moultonborough Academy")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Search']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='hsCode']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#approvedCourseTable_1 th.header")))])
  ```
- Using `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "state")))).select_by_visible_text("New Hampshire")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city']").send_keys("Moultonborough")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys("Moultonborough Academy")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='hsCode']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='approvedCourseTable_1']//th[@class='header']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Course\nWeight', 'Title', 'Notes', 'Max\nCredits', 'OK\nThrough', 'Disability\nCourse']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To complete, if you really want to remove the `br` tags, you can use (I've fixed your XPath expression) :

```
import re
courses_subheading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//tr[th[@class='header']])[1]/th")
headers = [re.sub('\s+',' ',el.text) for el in courses_subheading]
print(headers)
```

Output :

```
['Course Weight', 'Title', 'Notes', 'Max Credits', 'OK Through', 'Disability Course']
```