# Using logical to index list and convert values

Tags: python, list

I have a list in which I am trying to replace empty strings with 0. Is there a way to do this other than iterating through each item in the list?

Here's a smaller example of what my list is like:

```
testlist=['',18.0,'','',0,15,8.0]
```

In Matlab, I know I could do something like this:

```
testlist[testlist=='']=0
```

but this only seems to change the first value (even if its something other than an empty string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace values in list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python)

Comment: boolean indexing is part of numpy not normal python lists `import numpy;testlist=numpy.array(['',18.0,'','',0,15,8.0]);testlist[testlist=='']=0`

Answer (score 2):

In python you can use a list comprehension:

```
A = ['', 18.0, '', '', 0, 15, 8.0]
```

Here this subsequent A has the `''` values replaced with `0`'s.

```
A = [x if x != '' else 0 for x in A]
```

Comment: Ok. I can just use list comprehension. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways:

The first way is using a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) like the other answer does:

```
a = ['',18.0,'','',0,15,8.0]
b = [x if x != '' else 0 for x in a]
```

This reads like: 'Make an array b with each element x of a for which if x is not '' then put x, else put 0'.

There is also an awesome library called [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) which utilizes a syntax that looks like the syntax from Matlab you are referring to:

```
import numpy as np
a = ['',18.0,'','',0,15,8.0]
# Create a numpy array from the list
b = np.array(a)
b[b == ''] = 0
print(b)
>>> array(['0', '18.0', '0', '0', '0', '15', '8.0'],
  dtype='<U4')
```

The array is now an array of strings, which you can convert to a float or something else using `np.ndarray.astype(type)`.

Considering you've referred Matlab's syntax, I suggest having a look at numpy. When writing scripts in Python, you will notice numpy and Matlab share a lot of syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, brvh. I'll look into numpy in the future.