# Appending numbers from a file into a list by it's value

Tags: python

I have a file containing numerical values:

```
1
4
6
10
12
```

and I'm trying to append these values into its respective position in an array where i would obtain:

```
[None,1,None,None,4,None,6,None,None,None,10,None,None,12]
```

Since 1 from the file would be at index 1 in the list, 4 from the file would be at index 4 in the list and so on.

I begin by first reading in the file:

```
filename = open("numbers.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
numfile = filename

lst = [None] * 12

for line in numfile:
    line = line.strip()   #strip new line
    line = int(line)       #making the values in integer form  

    vlist.append(line)   #was thinking of line[val] where value is the number itself.
print(vlist)
```

but I'm getting the output:

```
[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,1,4,6,10,12]
```

Where the numbers are appended to the far right of the array. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Try lst[num] = num

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace values in list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to a list adds the numbers at the end of the list. You instead want to assign the value of `line` to the list at the index of `line`

```
filename = open("numbers.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
numfile = filename

lst = [None] * 13

for line in numfile:
    line = line.strip()   #strip new line
    line = int(line)       #making the values in integer form  
    lst[line] = line  

print(lst)
# [None, 1, None, None, 4, None, 6, None, None, None, 10, None, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your number as `int`egers in a list called `numbers` (*which you have no problem doing as it seems*), you can do:

```
lst = [None if i not in numbers else i for i in range(max(numbers)+1)]
```

if `numbers` can be a big list, I would cast it to `set` first to make the `in` comparisons faster.

```
numbers = set(numbers)
lst = [None if i not in numbers else i for i in range(max(numbers)+1)]
```

---

Example

```
>>> numbers = [1, 4, 6, 10, 12]
>>> [None if i not in numbers else i for i in range(max(numbers) + 1)]
[None, 1, None, None, 4, None, 6, None, None, None, 10, None, 12]
```

Comment: Nice I need to pratice about the pythonic style, I'm too used of using regular programming structures

Comment: If this `[None, 1, None, None, 4, None, 6, None, None, None, 10, None, None]` is expected, your code might not work

Comment: @Cid You do seem to have a Fortran background ☺. That is a good thing though!

Comment: @Cid But this is not what is expected.. What do you mean by that?

Comment: If his file contains `[1, 4, 6, 10]` and he expects a 13-sized list as shown in the OP example

Comment: I started with C, not Fortran :)

Comment: @Cid Oh, I see. But my understanding is that the size of the list depends on the largest number in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to a list in a loop is expensive. I advise your construct a list of `None` items and then iterate your list to update elements.

Below is a demo with `itertools` and `csv.reader`:

```
from io import StringIO
from itertools import chain
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""1
4
6
10
12""")

# replace mystr with open('numbers.txt', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    num_list = list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(reader)))

res = [None] * (num_list[-1]+1)

for i in num_list:
    res[i] = i

print(res)

[None, 1, None, None, 4, None, 6, None, None, None, 10, None, 12]
```

---

Benchmarking example:

```
def appender1(n):
    return [None]*int(n)

def appender2(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(int(n)):
        lst.append(None)
    return lst

%timeit appender1(1e7)  # 90.4 ms per loop
%timeit appender2(1e7)  # 1.77 s per loop
```

Comment: Don't you have to append to a list when you build num_list?  How can that be more efficient than initializing `res` before opening the file, and just setting one element of `res` for each line in the file?

Comment: @PaulCornelius, See my benchmarking example. You only know the length of your list *after* reading the file. So you can use `num_list[-1]` to get the last element (the largest, since your example assumes ordering) and use this to calculate the length.

Comment: Of course appending one at a time is much slower than allocating the whole array at once.  It seems there's some doubt about how to interpret the question - OP started by declaring an array of None's (but didn't make it big enough to include element with an index of 12).  You're assuming that the values in the file are sorted.  Your guess is definitely as good as mine :-)

Comment: It's not so much that `list.append` in a loop is expensive (it's not, relatively speaking, it is an optimized amortized constant time operation), but that looping at the python interpreter level is much slower than looping at the C-level, which list-repetition does.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thank your insight, yep I do understand that the issue is with Python interpreter overhead of a `for` loop vs C loop, I wasn't trying to pin it down to `list.append`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an indexer and compare its value with the actual value of the line, and replace the value at the index rather than

```
filename = open("numbers.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
numfile = filename

lst = [None] * 12
i = 0
for line in numfile:
    line = line.strip()   #strip new line
    line = int(line)       #making the values in integer form  
    value = None
    if (i == line):
        value = line
    if (len(vlist) < line): #replace or append if there's more numbers in the file than the size of the list
        vlist[i] = value
    else:
        vlist.append(value) 
    i += 1
print(vlist)
```