# How to replace a element in list of list using python3?

Tags: python, list

How to replace a element in list of list using python3?

```
txt =[[""],[""],[""]]
for i in txt:
   x = i.replace("", "apples")
   print(x)
```

> Expected Output:

```
apples
apples
apples
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace values in list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python)

Comment: i am asking for list of list

Comment: You can just use an answer from the question I have linked and apply it to all elements in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def replace(value, new_value, outer_list):    
  for inner_list in outer_list:
    for i,element in enumerate(inner_list):
       if element == value:
          inner_list[i]= new_value
  return outer_list
txt =[[""],[""],[""]]
txt = replace("", "apple", txt)
```

This function could do your need

Answer (score 1):

To replace every instance of `""` in the sublists of the main list `txt`, you can use the following list-comprehension:

```
txt =[[""],[""],[""]]
txt = [[x if not x=="" else 'apples' for x in sublist] for sublist in txt]
```

which produces:

```
[['apples'], ['apples'], ['apples']]
```

---

The code you have right now cannot work because given the way you loop over `txt`, `i` is the sublist and you python list objects do not have a `.replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
txt = [[""],[""],[""]]
for i in range(len(txt)):
    for ii in range(len(txt[i])):
        txt[i][ii] = (txt[i][ii]).replace("","apples")
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
txt =[[""],[""],[""]]

print([[x if x != "" else 'apples' for x in sub] for sub in txt])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[['apples'], ['apples'], ['apples']]
```

To print them separately;

```
txt = [[x if x != "" else 'apples' for x in sub] for sub in txt]

for sub in txt:
   for elem in sub:
      print(elem)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
apples
apples
apples
```