# How to filter Python list while keeping filtered values zero

Tags: python, list

With

> input = [0,0,5,9,0,4,10,3,0]

as list
I need an output, which is going to be two highest values in input while setting other list elements to zero.

> output = [0,0,0,9,0,0,10,0,0]

The closest I got:

```
from itertools import compress
import numpy as np
import operator
input= [0,0,5,9,0,4,10,3,0]
top_2_idx = np.argsort(test)[-2:]
test[top_2_idx[0]]
test[top_2_idx[1]]
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace values in list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python)

Comment: What if the maximum appears more than twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort, find the two largest values, and then use a list comprehension:

```
input = [0,0,5,9,0,4,10,3,0]
*_, c1, c2 = sorted(input)
result = [0 if i not in {c1, c2} else i for i in input]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
```

Comment: While it's neat, this is O(n log(n)), but can be done in O(n) with a single traversal

Comment: @Ajax1234 @Olivier For an O(n) solution you could use `heapq.nlargest` rather than `sorted`.

Answer (score 5):

Not as pretty as Ajax's solution but a `O(n)` solution and a little more dynamic:

```
from collections import deque

def zero_non_max(lst, keep_top_n):
    """
    Returns a list with all numbers zeroed out
    except the keep_top_n.
    >>> zero_non_max([0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 4, 10, 3, 0], 3)
    >>> [0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
    """

    lst = lst.copy()

    top_n = deque(maxlen=keep_top_n)

    for index, x in enumerate(lst):
        if len(top_n) < top_n.maxlen or x > top_n[-1][0]:
            top_n.append((x, index))
        lst[index] = 0

    for val, index in top_n:
        lst[index] = val

    return lst

lst = [0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 4, 10, 3, 0]
print(zero_non_max(lst, 2))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to achieve this with a single list traversal, making the algorithm *O(n)*:

- First find the two highest values with a single traversal;
- Then create a list of zeros and add in the found maxima.

#### Code

```
def two_max(lst):
    # Find two highest values in a single traversal
    max_i, max_j = 0, 1
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        _, max_i, max_j = sorted((max_i, max_j, i), key=lst.__getitem__)

    # Make a new list with zeros and replace both maxima
    new_lst = [0] * len(lst)
    new_lst[max_i], new_lst[max_j] = lst[max_i], lst[max_j]

    return new_lst


lst = [0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 4, 10, 3, 0]

print(two_max(lst)) # [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
```

Note that if the maximum value in the list appears more than twice, only the two left-most values will appear.

As a sidenote, do not use names such as `input` in your code as this overshadows the built-in function of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Pure **numpy** approach:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 4, 10, 3, 0])
top_2_idx = np.argsort(arr)[-2:]
np.put(arr, np.argwhere(~np.isin(arr, arr[top_2_idx])), 0)
print(arr)
```

The output:

```
[ 0  0  0  9  0  0 10  0  0]
```

[Numpy.put](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `numpy`-based solution that avoids sorting the entire array, which takes `O(nlogn)` time.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0,0,5,9,0,4,10,3,0])
arr[np.argpartition(arr,-2)[:-2]] = 0
```

If you want to create a new array as output:

```
result = np.zeros_like(arr)
idx = np.argpartition(arr,-2)[-2:]
result[idx] = arr[idx]
```

A corresponding Python-native solution is to use `heap.nlargest`, which also avoids sorting the entire array.

```
import heapq

arr = [0,0,5,9,0,4,10,3,0]
l = len(arr)
idx1, idx2 = heapq.nlargest(2, range(l), key=arr.__getitem__)
result = [0] * l
result[idx1] = arr[idx1]
result[idx2] = arr[idx2]
```