# Editing list using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I want to change all the number in this list so that it will add 1.5 to anything that smaller than 0 until they are larger than 0, however, I don't understand why it would produce a very strange output ([1, 1, 1, 1, -3.5, -2.5, -4, -5, 0.5])

```
for i in y:
    if i<0:
        y[i] = i+1.5

print (y)
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `y`?

Answer (score 2):

You were mixing the indexes and elements of the list.
And you needed a while instead of the "if" to keep going until you reach the wanted number.

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    while y[i] < 0:
        y[i]+=1.5
```

Comment: what if I want to apply a fairly complex function (like a*i+b*i^2) to the y[i] that's smaller than 0, and the 'a' decreases by half every time it's used? (I was reading about nested loops, but I haven't learned them in class yet...)

Comment: Sorry, not sure of what you need but to decrease a number by half at each iteration, you can use: "a/=2" inside a loop. With this, each time you loop, a is divided by 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo:

```
for i, n in enumerate(y):
    if n < 0:
        y[i] %= 1.5
```

Comment: what if I want to apply a fairly complex function (like a*i+b*i^2) to the y[i] that's smaller than 0, and the 'a' decreases by half every time it's used? (I was reading about nested loops, but I haven't learned them in class yet...)

Answer (score 0):

Python iterates by value, by default. To iterate by index, you have to make a list of indices and iterate through *that*. You do this with the built-in `range()`:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    while y[i] < 0:
        y[i] += 1.5
print(y)
```

Comment: what if I want to apply a fairly complex function (like a*i+b*i^2) to the y[i] that's smaller than 0, and the 'a' decreases by half every time it's used? (I was reading about nested loops, but I haven't learned them in class yet...)

Comment: In that case I would declare `a = some_value` before the nested `while` loop, and then inside the nested loop just decrease it every time. This way, every iteration of the `for` loop it gets reset. Nested loops shouldn't need explanation - they work exactly like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540071/7432276):

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, -3.5, -2.5, -4, -5, -0.5]
>>> x = [i if i>0 else ((i%-1.5)+1.5) for i in x]
>>> print(x)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(your_list)):
    if your_list[i] < 0:
    your_list[i] += 1.5
print(your_list)
```

Comment: and if you want to do the way you did with foreach
for i in your_list:
   if i < 0:
     your_list[your_list.index(i)] += 1.5
print(your_list)