# How do I replace elements in a list?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a loop that replaces all the elements of the list with elements that are half a big. If the list is [1,2,3,4]  the new list should read [0.5,1,1.5,2].
WITHOUT CREATING A NEW LIST!

I tried the following

```
for i in Glist:
    i = Glist[i]/2
    Glist.append(i)
```

And hot an error : list index out of range
how to stop the loop?

also tried this:

```
for i in mylist:
    i = i/2
    mylist.append(i)
```

did not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace values in list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to *replace* elements of a list, then the length of the list should not change, which `append` does.  Instead:

```
for i,v in enumerate(Glist):
    Glist[i] = v/2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that iterating over a list while appending to it is a perfect recipe for an *endless loop*. Besides iiuc you want to modify the actual elements, here you're just appending to the end of the list.

You could use a regular for loop and just modify *in-place* with:

```
for i in range(len(Glist)):
    Glist[i] /= 2.
```

---

```
print(Glist)
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
```