# How do I change an item in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, linear-search

I have a list, and I want to find the value 20 in the list and if it is present, replace the first instance with 3.

```py
list1 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding and replacing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540049/replace-values-in-list-using-python ?

Answer (score 0):

Perform a linear search, or if the sequence can be disturbed, sort it and do a binary search. Then when 20 is found, note the index and replace it directly.
eg

```
flag=0;
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
{
  if(list1[i]==20 && flag==0)
  {
     list1[i]=3;
    flag=1;
  }
}
```

for python:
[finding and replacing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: i need the problem in python language

Comment: @RusuMihai https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list

Comment: You don't even need the flag. Just break as soon as you replace with 3.

Answer (score 0):

I did it directly.
This works for me:

```
while True:
    if 20 in list1:
        # getting index of the value
        val_index = list1.index(20)
        # replacing it by 3
        list1[val_index] = 3
        print(list1)
    else:
        break
```

and if you want only the first value should change then remove the while loop:

```
if 20 in list1:
    # getting index of the value
    val_index = list1.index(20)
    # replacing it by 3
    list1[val_index] = 3
    print(list1)
```

I hope this works :)